# Retrieving last one hour records from table with condition

Tags: mysql

**Objective:** I am fetching last one hour record from MySQL table in production with condition.

**Table Details:**

`orders`: User can order products. Each order could have multiple product while buying(cart based)(this is just to reference table details).

`order_info_new`: Each ordered product(parent and child) are logged here.

So when we any products into existing order i.e. making the product as child then new entry gets logged in order_info_new.

```
        select oi.id
             , orders.id 
          FROM store.order_info_new oi 
          join store.orders orders 
            on oi.orderId = orders.orderID 
         where oi.expiry > now()
           and orders.status = 'PAID' 
           and timestampdiff(minute,  orders.createdAt, oi.createdAt)>10 
           and oi.createdAt Between DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) and now();
```

Conditions : Order should be paid, Parent order and child order should have difference more than 10 mins and checking only for newly added order in last 1 hour.

**Problem:** After running the above query in staging I get response in 0.3 seconds while doing the same on production I get **Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query** means it is being timedout.

**Hint:** I think I don't have indexing in my table but in where clause how do I index when I don't have condition for it.

**UPDATED:** as per @CaffeinatedCod3r advice I added explain before select statement in production and staging what I found is that in type of oi I am getting Range in staging and Extra column - using index condition, using where but in production I am getting All in type column and using where only in extra

Comment: Try to compare the output of `EXPLAIN` from both the environment and then you can see what is causing time out.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r updated and attached ss in question

Comment: This makes it clear that in staging you have indexing in orderId column. Also to see the indexes in staging and prod `SHOW INDEXES FROM store.order_info_new ;`.You will see the columns which are indexed and type of indexing. You could create columns with same index in prod and then see the execution time.

Comment: You can't put a indexed query or any query in where condition. If you want to index  order expiry column in prod, you can run the query `CREATE INDEX order_expiry_idx ON store.order_info_new (expiry)`. Now your query optimizer will use that index in prod.

Comment: This is what I meant this expiry index is created at staging but not in production....I am not sure why....and I am not saying query the indexed what I meant is when I am doing it staging `oi.expiry>now()` since expiry is indexed therefore I am getting key as order_info_new_expiry but null in production....although it has to be checked in production by creating index to figure out if this was the case. Checking now

Comment: @CaffeinatedCod3r  My bad the index is already there in production for the same table. But why I am getting key as null when I do explain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220969/discussion-between-caffeinatedcod3r-and-kramer).

Answer (score 0):

Functions cannout use indexes, so `timestampdiff(minute,  orders.createdAt, oi.createdAt)>10` cannot use an index. However, the `orders.createdAt` part of `orders.createdAt BETWEEN oi.createdAt AND oi.created + INTERVAL 10 minute` can use an index, such as `(orders.status,orders.createdAt)`, or its inverse

Comment: I think it makes sense I have to do lot of stuff because can't mess with prod....I will take a dump to slavedb then test it.....Actually the scanning is very large amount of data so if I am using expiry as force indexing it brings half result but since expiry is not unique therefore doesn't make a large impact so I guess createdAt will do...will try today